# ios navigation controller push view controller but have back button point somewhere else

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller

The scenario I have is this. I have 5 view controllers: `Root`, `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`

I am currently on screen `B` and my navigation stack contains `Root`, `A`, `B`.

Once the user performs a certain action on `B` I want to navigate to `D` without any other screens showing, and I want the `back button` to point to `C`. The full navigation stack should look like: `Root` => `C` => `D`.

So effectively, I want to pop to my `root view controller`, then push `C`, and push `D`. However, I don't want `Root` and `C` to appear.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `setViewControllers:animated:` method in `B` to push an instance of `C` and `D` at the same time. It will look like a simple push to the user but in reality you are effectively popping and pushing multiple views.

Comment: How do I remove `A` from the stack?

Comment: because the array you pass to `setViewControllers:animated:` will only contain `C` and `D` view controllers

Comment: oh got it, awesome, will try this out